# How to determine the cause of a delay before an action is hit in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks, rack-mini-profiler

I've come to a dead-end with my troubleshooting, and I'm really hoping someone can help.

I'm using *rack-mini-profiler* to help locate a potential memory leak in my Rails website. I narrowed it down to the method that is being called.

High-level profile: [rack-mini-profiler high-level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW3SY.jpg)

SQL profile: [rack-mini-profiler results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxtp5.jpg)

In the SQL profile picture, notice the start times of the query just above and just below the gray bar have a difference of 1037ms. That is the delay I am noticing, and it grows until I restart the application.

When running this locally, I can monitor the terminal. When that method is requested, there is just that 1 second delay, and then it executes. No queries or commands show up in the terminal during that delay.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can figure out what is causing this delay?

I'm using Ruby 2.2.0 with Rails 4.1.6.

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

This is the method rack-mini-profiler is pointing to:

```rb
def submit_answer
    quiz_attempt = CourseCompletion.find_by_id(params[:course_completion_id]).quiz_started
    choice = Choice.new(:answer_id => params[:answer], :quiz_attempt_id => quiz_attempt.id)
    @success = choice.save
    @answer = choice.answer
    @question = @answer.question
    @quiz_attempt = choice.quiz_attempt
    render :layout => false
  end
```

Comment: `submit_answer` is the culprit.  There has to be something wrong there, can you share that method?

Comment: @RockwellRice Thanks, I've just included it in my description above. The website is a series of quizzes. That method gets called each time an answer to a question is submitted.

Comment: have you examined controller callbacks(hooks)? https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Callbacks

Comment: or model callbacks? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: what is in the view template of your action?

Comment: I would try removing some parts of the code (before_actions, code from the action, code from the view) to discard parts of it and narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look on ruby-prof [github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof). Try to wrap body of your action into the block:

```
require 'ruby-prof'

# profile the code
RubyProf.start
# ... code to profile ...
result = RubyProf.stop

# print a flat profile to text
printer = RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(result)
printer.print(STDOUT)
```

and you should receive output in console which would look like:
[image]

You also can redirect output of profiler to log or some file on the server.

So in your case edit code:

```
def submit_answer
    require 'ruby-prof'
    # profile the code
    RubyProf.start


    quiz_attempt = CourseCompletion.find_by_id(params[:course_completion_id]).quiz_started
    choice = Choice.new(:answer_id => params[:answer], :quiz_attempt_id => quiz_attempt.id)
    @success = choice.save
    @answer = choice.answer
    @question = @answer.question
    @quiz_attempt = choice.quiz_attempt
    render :layout => false

    result = RubyProf.stop
    # print a flat profile to text
    printer = RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(result)
    printer.print(STDOUT)
  end
```

Add to gemfile

```
gem 'ruby-prof'
```

Run `bundle install` and restart the server. Try to run action again and check rails console output. Methods on top of the table are most time consuming.